# Terraform: Error: Provider configuration not present

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

After Terraform upgrade from version **0.11.14** to **0.13.7** I got an error:

> Error: Invalid resource name
>
> on .terraform/modules/tflib/alb/main.tf line 53, in resource
> "aws_alb_listener" "443":   53: resource "aws_alb_listener" "443" {
>
> A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only
> letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.

So I have it renamed to `resource "aws_alb_listener" "https"`, but another error's thrown:

> Error: Provider configuration not present
>
> To work with module.tflib.module.alb.aws_alb_listener.443 its original
> provider configuration at provider["registry.terraform.io/-/aws"] is
> required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
> configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still
> exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
> module.tflib.module.alb.aws_alb_listener.443, after which you can
> remove the provider configuration again.

AWS Provider config:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      version = "~> 3.15"
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `required_providers` like it is specified here: https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#explicit-provider-source-locations?

Comment: Not yet! Should I do it inside tflib or it needs to be done on a top level?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it should be done only on the top level.

Comment: You should be upgrading from 11->12->13, not directly from 11->13. This can save you a lot of potential issues.

Comment: This is ambiguously covered in the upgrade guide at https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html#why-do-i-see-provider-during-init-. It is not always clear this is the root cause like in your situation, and the other SO questions solved by pointing at this doc are difficult to search for.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when I was updating TF from 0.11 to 0.13.
As other people already suggested I did 11>12>13 but nonetheless I got the same problem.

I think what happened is that the state had the old provider configuration, in this case is `aws` but it could be any other, so you could update the provider in your state to get the new compatible version like this

```sh
terraform state replace-provider 'registry.terraform.io/-/aws' 'registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws'
```